# Do all focusable elements have tabIndex 0 by default?

Tags: javascript, tabs, modal-dialog

I am trying to figure out how to properly make trapped focus inside modal and the way to get all elements that can get focused by keyboard inside modal. I found out that all interactive elements have tabIndex=0 property by default, and others have tabIndex -1. But there isnt any info about this in spec. Is it crossbrowser? Do guys that making guides about trapping focus in modal know that button, a, input have tabIndex property and they dont need to select those separatly or I am missing something.

Comment: [This is something clearly documented.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Answer (score 0):

The tabIndex IDL attribute must reflect the value of the tabindex content attribute. The default value is 0 if the element is an a, area, button, frame, iframe, input, object, select, textarea, or SVG a element, or is a summary element that is a summary for its parent details. The default value is −1 otherwise. But for some reason button with disabled attribute still have tabIndex property 0, that makes it harder and less performant to find focusable Elements